# In javascript, or with a jQuery plugin, to completely scale a div and its contents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, scale

I'm looking to achieve an effect as seen on the metalabs site's image changer/slider:

http://metalabdesign.com/

I got it working, but the catch is that I'm not using images, I'm scaling a div with content inside it. Dynamic content that's subject to change. Is there a way I can just blow up the whole div and its contents, because manually scaling each element inside the div is a huge hassle.

I'm currently scaling a div with a jQuery animation:

Starting css:

```
#tagBox {
    display: none;
    width: 1280px;
    height: 1000px;
    position: absolute !important;
    left: 50% !important;
    margin-left: -640px;
    top: 50% !important;
    margin-top: -500px;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

The jQuery that changes it.

```
$('#tagBox').show().animate({
    opacity: 1,
    width: 700,
    height: 500,
    marginLeft: '+=275px',
    marginTop: '+=250px'
}
```

But that only animated the div. The div's contents stay fixed in the upper right corner. I'm looking for a way to imitate the animation, but just scale the div as a whole, all elements together, preferably in normal javascript.

Thanks!

Comment: There are some CSS-properties that allow you to scale elements, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665406/resize-html-map-images/7665568#7665568 . You may create a cssHook in jQuery for ease of use.

Comment: I don't dabble much with animate() so I can't offer a proper answer; however, knowing CSS2 a bit (still learning CSS3 animations), you'll want to take inventory of the div's contents-- make sure padding, margins, etc., are being set with a measurement based on the parent (%?). This should theoretically take care of layout. I suspect you'd need a separate animate call for the text size; as long as the time interval is the same, animating font-size from X to zero at the same time as a div is animated in size from Y to zero should allow everything to scale.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use css3 transformations.

```
-webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
-moz-transform: scale(1.2);
-o-transform: scale(1.2);
-ms-transform: scale(1.2);
```

Check It - http://jsfiddle.net/6gJka/2/.

Comment: How can I do that after a jQuery click function?

Comment: How do I do cross-browser support with that method?

Comment: How do I add the opacity back into this?

Comment: Also, it still isn't cross browser, you just added cross-browser transitions. I need ross-browser transforms.